# Issue translation for description product

Tags: sylius

In my case, there are three languages for my site. In backoffice, Product management, I have only one textarea to product description. Obviously, one description in english is not suitable to my chinese and franch site. So i add three columns in Entity product

description_en, description_fr, description_cn

than I do description_%local% to show them in View twig.

Is there another solution to do this ? thank you very much for sharing your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use doctrine translatable extension. Take a look at this PR as an example https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/110